# Mysql - fazer cada linha incrementar 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Quero fazer uma consulta *sql* e quero que cada linha tenha uma coluna indicando o numero da linha ex:

```
linha     nome
1          joao
2          maria
3          tiago
.          .
.          .
.          .
n          joares
```

Mas, essa coluna "linha" eu não tenho na tabela, então estou tentando fazer algo tipo:

```
select count(nome), nome from pessoas;
```

O problema é que quando eu uso ***count***() ou ***sum***() o resultado sai agrupado, como se eu tivesse feito ou **group by nome**  então como proceder ?

Comment: Testa isto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13550826/2256325

Comment: @Sergio obrigado, será que existe uma outra solução digamos assim mais simples onde eu execute apenas 1 instruções no banco?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para evitar a declaração você pode utilizar a variável como uma tabela:

```
select 
    @num := @num + 1,
    u.usu_nome 
from tab_usuario u, (SELECT @num := 0) as t
group by u.usu_id;
```

Comment: Isso sim, é a solução que eu buscava, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Achei essa solução:

```
set @num = 0 ;
select 
    @num := @num + 1 ,
    u.usu_nome from tab_usuario u
    group by u.usu_id;
```

Mas queria uma solução só com o select, sem ter que fazer esse **set** de uma variável