# Mysql -> Atribuir Id's a registos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Então, estou a ter dúvidas em algo que talvez não seja complicado, eu queria atribuir valores (id's) aos registos que retornassem disto:

```
SELECT * FROM `aldeias` where `userid`='-1'
```

Fazendo isto, vai retornar apenas os id's das aldeias sem dono (-1), mas vão ser os id's delas

```
|ID | ALDEIA | DONO

|1 | Aldeia 1 |-1

|3 | Aldeia 1 |-1

|7 | Aldeia 1 |-1

|8 | Aldeia 1 |-1
```

Queria que ficasse algo assim:

```
ID.. |ID | ALDEIA | DONO

1  |1 | Aldeia 1 |-1

2  |3 | Aldeia 1 |-1

3  |7 | Aldeia 1 |-1

4  |8 | Aldeia 1 |-1
```

Comment: sua coluna ID que possui os numeros fora de ordem já é chave primária ?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O MySql não possui as funções de janela (window funtions) do SQL Server, assim, tens que fazer manualmente. Eu faria

```
SELECT  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ID_RN
       ,t.ID 
       ,t.ALDEIA 
       ,t.DONO
  FROM aldeias t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
 WHERE userid = -1
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui o que queria :)

Comment: Vou dar +1 porque achei muito boa sua resposta, ficou no ponto que o AP precisa ;) rsrssr

Answer (score 1):

O valor da coluna **DONO** para Aldeias sem dono poderia ser **0** e não **-1**.

Daí você faria:

`Select * From Aldeias Where Dono = 0`

Retornará todas as aldeias que não têm dono.

Comment: Eu quero que todas os registos com userid -1 fossem retornados com id's ordenados.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade seu problema se resume ao mesmo problema que eu tinha aqui

[Mysql - fazer cada linha incrementar 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65516/mysql-fazer-cada-linha-incrementar-1)

Vou deixar um exemplo que resolve seu problema ainda nao testei com os nomes da sua tabela mas rodei com minhas tabelas aqui e funcionou

`select 
     @num := @num + 1 as ID,
    'Aldeia 1' as Aldeia,'-1' as Dono from aldeias, (SELECT @num := 0) as t where`userid`='-1';`